# How to fetch certain value from Dictionary in ansible

Tags: json, list, dictionary, ansible

This is my list of dictionary

```
json:
    datasets:
    - createTime: '2020-01-10T18:18:29.010162Z'
      displayName: video_dataset
      name: projects/000111/locations/us-central1/datasets/123456789
    - createTime: '2020-01-10T18:18:29.010162Z'
      displayName: manual_dataset
      name: projects/000111/locations/us-central1/datasets/00556685
    - createTime: '2020-01-10T18:18:29.010162Z'
      displayName: wrong_dataset
      name: projects/000111/locations/us-central1/datasets/19967845
```

I am trying to fetch 5th element from "name" key if the list has displayName = video_dataset.

so the out put here would be 123456789.

Here is my ansible script and one of the method is using json_query:

```
- name: get dataset id
  set_fact : 
    dataset_ID: "{{ dataset_list.json.datasets | json_query([displayName=='video_dataset'].name.split('/')[5]) }}"
```

which gives me error saying,

```
Undefine Variable : 'displayName'
```

I tried several methods but no luck. Any advice would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `{{ json.datasets | selectattr('display_name', '==', 'video_dataset') | map(attribute='name') | map('regex_replace', '^.*/(\\d*)$', '\\1') }}`. Written on spot on my phone so untested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: ***"Fetch 5th element from 'name' key."***

A: There is no *split* function in [JmesPath](https://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specification.html#). You can *map* the [Ansible filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#manipulating-strings) instead. For example,

```yaml
dataset_ID: "{{ json.datasets|json_query(dataset_ID_query)|
                              map('split', '/')|
                              map(attribute=5)|
                              list }}"
dataset_ID_query: '[?displayName == `video_dataset`].name'
```

---

Notes

- Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    json:
      datasets:
      - createTime: '2020-01-10T18:18:29.010162Z'
        displayName: video_dataset
        name: projects/000111/locations/us-central1/datasets/123456789
      - createTime: '2020-01-10T18:18:29.010162Z'
        displayName: manual_dataset
        name: projects/000111/locations/us-central1/datasets/00556685
      - createTime: '2020-01-10T18:18:29.010162Z'
        displayName: wrong_dataset
        name: projects/000111/locations/us-central1/datasets/19967845

    dataset_ID: "{{ json.datasets|json_query(dataset_ID_query)|
                                  map('split', '/')|
                                  map(attribute=5)|
                                  list }}"
    dataset_ID_query: '[?displayName == `video_dataset`].name'

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: dataset_ID
    - debug:
        var: dataset_ID.0
    - debug:
        var: dataset_ID|first
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
dataset_ID:
  - '123456789'
dataset_ID.0: '123456789'
dataset_ID|first: '123456789'
```

---

- Make the code more robust and use the filter [*last*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.last) if you want to fetch the last element. For example, the declaration below gives the same result

```yaml
dataset_ID: "{{ json.datasets|json_query(dataset_ID_query)|
                              map('split', '/')|
                              map('last')|
                              list }}"
```

---

- Simplify the code and use the filter [*basename*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names) to get the last element from the path. For example, the declaration below gives the same result

```yaml
dataset_ID: "{{ json.datasets|json_query(dataset_ID_query)|
                              map('basename')|
                              list }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it works.
But the dataset_ID comes as object in list. any idea on how to get it as normal output '123456789 ' and not as object in list like  ['123456789'] .
Thanks again.

Comment: *dataset_ID* is a list because there might be more *datasets* that fit the condition. Simply select the first item from the list ``"{{ dataset_ID.0 }}"`` if you want to.

Comment: this is what i was looking for: {{ json.datasets | json_query(query) | map('split', '/') | map(attribute=5) | list | first}}